# How can I download different applications itunes, etc.?

Tags: installation, downloads

this is what it says everytime i try to download something

```
 Archive:  /home/user/Desktop/untitled folder/iTunes64Setup.exe
[/home/user/Desktop/untitled folder/iTunes64Setup.exe]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/user/Desktop/untitled folder/iTunes64Setup.exe or
          /home/user/Desktop/untitled folder/iTunes64Setup.exe.zip, and cannot find /home/user/Desktop/untitled folder/iTunes64Setup.exe.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more description? When do you see this error message? In the browser? When you try to unarchive? Also note that you're trying to install a Windows application, which won't work unless you use something like Wine or Virtualbox to emulate Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to run a Windows installer, but Ubuntu is not Windows. Ubuntu is trying to extract compressed files from the exe-file, perceiving it to be a self-extracting zip-file, which it is not.

The first thing you should do, is to find out why you want to use Itunes. Is it possible that there are other players that are better suited to your needs?

I don't think Itunes can be used on other platforms than OS X and Windows. If you really have to use it, then you'll need to install Wine or you can install Windows in virtualbox or something and run Itunes on that.

Answer (score 2):

By default Ubuntu tries to open an .exe file as if it is a zip archive (to be able to work with self-extracting zip archives, I suppose). iTunes installer is not a zip archive - that is why the operation fails.

As root45 has noted, Ubuntu does not support running Windows .exe files directly - you need to install Wine to run the application directly in Ubuntu or use VirtualBox with a Windows copy running in a virtual machine.

If you sill sure you want to run that file - try saving it to disk first (select "Save as" instead of "Open" when Firefox asks you, or right-click on the link and select "save taget as" instead of just clicking.

Actually, looking at your error message, I think that the file may be already downloaded to a folder called "untitled-folder" on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open it, first write in a terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.2
```

after that you can open it by doing double click, or by terminal, whatever you want.

However I prefer to use virtualbox-ose, but first you need a windows ISO or CD. You install a virtual machine, that could be pretty embed on your desktop using the seamless mode, it's awesome.

In that way I use windows applications like powerpoint, sketchbook and even watch some movies on netflix..as they run native on linux.

By the way, why do you want iTunes? have you ever tried Rythmbox? is a little bit uglier but functional..it goes well with my iPod too.